# How to pass value to pagination DataSourcec in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, datasource

I have to fetch pagination data based on a particular id. The id is getting in activity through intents.
Then how can i pass that value to my datasource.
I am using mvvm architecture

Comment: get data from intents, pass it to view model, and then you can send that to data source.

Comment: the datasource for the pagination is initialized on viewmodel creation time. so how can i pass my value to datasource

Comment: your view model will be lazy initialized, so when your view model is initializing, at that time you will have the data, and you can forward that data into view model constructor.

Comment: you using java or kotlin ?

Comment: am using kotlin

Answer (score 0):

So you can do something like that

Activity

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var value: Int = 0
    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this, MainActivityViewModel.Factory(value)).get(
            MainActivityViewModel::class.java
        )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

        /*
        * get data from intent here and assign to value like
        */ 
        value=intent.getIntExtra("keyName",0)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    }

}
```

As our view model is lazy initalized so only the updated value it will get.

Now your view model

```
class MainActivityViewModel(value: Int) : BaseViewModel() {

    init {
/*
do initiaize your data source here now
*/

    }

    class Factory(val value: Int) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return MainActivityViewModel(value) as T
            }
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Unable to construct viewmodel")
        }
    }
}
```

Now inside init block you can initialize your data source. Now you have the value in view model which was send through intent. I am using factory for view model creation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro. finally i have found solution to the problem.

Comment: if it did work for you, please do accept the answer, thanks